# How to limit cin to integers within the int data range?

Tags: c++

I am wondering how to only allow inputs for a cin which are within the int data range.

```
// This program counts the number of digits in an integer
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, k;
    cout << setw(20) << "Value Entered" << setw(20) << "Number of Digits" << endl;
    while(1==1)
    {
        k = 1;
        cout << setw(10) << "";
        cin >> i;
        while(i > 2147483647 || i < -2147483648)
        {
        cout << setw(10) << "";
        cin >> i;            
        }
        while( i / 10 > 0)
        {
            i = i / 10;
            k++;
        }
        cout << setw(30) << k << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the method I have it just gets stuck in the loop repeating 1.

EDIT:

Sample Output Format (Required)

```
    "Value Entered"   "Number of Digits"
          14                  2
         225                  3
       -1000                  4
```

Sample Output (What I have)

```
       Value Entered    Number of Digits
          45
                             2
          456
                             3
          258
                             3
          -2546
                             4
```

Comment: Also, another, less important, problem I'm having is I want the cin inputs to right justify instead of left justify.

Comment: If you want to set alignmnet along with `std::setw(...)` you can pass `std::right` as an `ostream` modifier. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left

Comment: `while(1==1) { ... }` this loop will never exit unless you have an explicit command to exit the loop. `break` is a common way to exit. What trigger do you want to cause the loop to exit?

Comment: Also, according to your code, -1000 has 1 digit.

Comment: Although to answer what is probably your question, your data validation won't work. `int` can only hold between [-2^31, 2^31 - 1]. So your check for values outside the range will never return true.

Comment: While(1==1) is just so it repeats. It's a school assignment, just what he told us to do. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extraction will fail if the number falls outside of the range for the type that it's being read into. When this happens the state of the stream will be set to failure, so you simply need to check for this state, and then reset the stream to a valid state:

```
while (!(cin >> i)) {
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(numeric_limit<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

`clear()` clears the error flags and `ignore()` puts the stream on a new line so that new data can be read. You may need to include `<limits>` for the code to work.

The condition for your second loop should be `while (i > 0)`. As you had it you were off by one digit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to change it to while(abs(i) > 0) but it is working great now!

Comment: Is there a way to get this so it doesn't end the line? I am supposed to have them formatted as a table

Comment: @Dxccr Can you give me an example of the format of the table?

Comment: I can't get the formatting in the comment, I will edit in the post

Comment: @Dxccr You may want to ask another question for that issue.

Comment: The two problems I'm having are a line break after the cin, and the "Values Entered" are left justified. I will post a sample of that as well.

Comment: I'm locked out from questions for two days :( assignment is due Thursday. I am looking everywhere on google, but I can't find it. Everywhere I've looked says that cin just ends the line because the user hits enter to input the data

Comment: Regardless, thanks so much for your help. You seriously rock!

Comment: @Dxccr I think you would need to do something like `cout << setw(14) << i << setw(16) << k << endl;`. Does that work?